# Azure Cosmos DB - get children only with Self JOIN

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, self-join

I'm struggling to get the result I want from Cosmos DB.

My collection could be represented as :

```
[{
   ...,
  "category": null
  "code": "A."
},
{
   ...
  "category": "A."
  "code": "A2."
},
{
   ...,
  "category": "A."
  "code": "A1."
},
{
   ...,
  "category": "A1."
  "code": "A12."
}]
```

Where each document can be linked to another through the category field.

I would like to retrieve last children only: those whose code property is not used as a category in another document, so with the previous data set the desired output would be :
[{
   ...,
  "category": "A."
  "code": "A2."
},
{
   ...,
  "category": "A1."
  "code": "A12."
}]

In SQL I could write it this way:

```sql
SELECT c.code FROM c WHERE c.code NOT IN (SELECT category FROM c)
```

Comment: What do you mean `those whose code is not used as a category`,please show us your desired output format.

Comment: In my example, it would only return:
{
   ...,
  "category": "A1."
  "code": "A12."
}
because "A12." is never used as a category in other documents

Comment: So all the object elements are different documents or they are included in one array?

Comment: No other filter condition? No sort rules?

Comment: They are different documents, no other conditions, I just need the last leaves of my tree

Comment: Is your _collection_ a single Cosmos document with a property that contains a JSON array as shown in your question or are the four JSON objects really four different documents in Cosmos? In the later case I'm pretty sure that you cannot create a Cosmos SQL query that will do what you want. Cosmos is not a relational database.

Comment: No they are four different Documents. And yes I've also come to the conclusion that I couldn't achieve this with a single query, so for now I've decided to add a boolean property to each Document I want to retrieve, it's not that bad, I was just mislead by the SQL syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `Array_Slice` to get the last element in the array.Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-array-slice).

[image]

```
SELECT ARRAY_SLICE(array,-1)[0] FROM c
```

Comment: It's not helping as none of my documents contain arrays.
I think what I want to achieve is impossible with Cosmos DB as it requires something similar to a cross-documents join which is not supported atm: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6611247-support-cross-document-joins